# What happened to NewsGator and FeedDemon?

Tags: rss

It's been a while since I used NewsGator and FeedDemon.  I tried to log on last week and today and both seem broken.

NewsGator no longer has a login -- it has been replaced by DataWire on the www.newsgator.com home page and my login no longer works.  FeedDemon is completely broken -- it is no longer sucking in RSS feeds.

What happened?  And what do I do now?  Do I need to get a completely new RSS feeder?  Or is there something else that NewsGator is doing that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newsgator no longer offers feed synchronization.  FeedDemon still works except for feeds that you had sync'd via Newsgator.  The [latest version of FeedDemon](http://www.newsgator.com/individuals/feeddemon/default.aspx) supports sync via Google Reader.

[Nick's blog](http://nick.typepad.com/) has lots of information on the v3 changes.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't even know v3 exited.  When I hit Help/Check New Version in v2.7 it says that no new version is available!

Comment: Did this and everything worked perfectly.  Even better, my Google Reader now automagically has all of my FeedDemon feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional news readers aren't doing that great; it's not just NewsGator and FeedDemon. Try using Google Reader, it's free and works anywhere. To get offline support, you can use [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) to save your Google Reader feeds offline.

Comment: Note that exporting feeds from FeedDemon and importing them into Google Reader should be easy using OPML export/import.